# Inno setup compiler How to set launching image during app loading

Tags: inno-setup, desktop-application

How do I enable showing a loading image when user launches my app
compiled with inno setup compiler?

For example if you launch ms word, you will see a loading image before
the main app loads in full.

Can this be done with Inno Setup?

I want my app to show a logo before loading fully, just as most app do?

Thank in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have gotten solution to my question above :) . Since I used wxpython for my GUI, there is a demo code on SplashScreen and AdvancedSplash things available within wxpython demo software.

**By the way @TLama, thanks for point to me the technical name of this functionality.**

Here are the working codes;

**#For wx.SplashScreen**

```
bitmap = wx.Bitmap('splashImage.png', wx.BITMAP_TYPE_PNG)
splash = wx.SplashScreen(bitmap, wx.SPLASH_CENTRE_ON_SCREEN | wx.SPLASH_TIMEOUT, 10000, None, style = wx.SIMPLE_BORDER | wx.STAY_ON_TOP | wx.SPLASH_CENTRE_ON_PARENT)
wx.Yield()
```

**#wx.AdvancedSplash**

```
import wx
import wx.lib.agw.advancedsplash as AS

app = wx.App(0)
frame = wx.Frame(None, -1, "AdvancedSplash Test")

imagePath = "my_splash_image.png"

bitmap = wx.Bitmap(imagePath, wx.BITMAP_TYPE_PNG)

shadow = wx.WHITE

splash = AS.AdvancedSplash(frame, bitmap=bitmap, timeout=5000, agwStyle=AS.AS_TIMEOUT | AS.AS_CENTER_ON_PARENT | AS.AS_SHADOW_BITMAP, shadowcolour=shadow)

app.MainLoop()
```

Answer (score 3):

Umar, what you are requesting is generally referred to as a splash-screen. The third party Inno Setup Script Includes (ISSI) library contains a function for splash-screens. http://members.home.nl/albartus/inno/ISSI_Functions/issi_splash.htm

Add the functionality by following the three steps found in the general instructions how to implement ISSI functions: http://members.home.nl/albartus/inno/

Comment: I wrote [`some library`](https://code.google.com/p/inno-image-animator/) to animate sequence of transparent PNG files (which can be used for static image using just one file) for one Stack Overflow question, but due to function names I used there I was hesitating to mention it. It's worth to mention that what prevents you from using a built-in custom form for this purpose is just the lack of missing timer functionality in Inno Setup.

Comment: Brownie points for your library TLama because you've published the source. If I were to implement a splash-screen in Inno I'd most probably start with yours.

Comment: @ Lars, I have studied the content of the link you provided: http://members.home.nl/albartus/inno/ISSI_Functions/issi_splash.htm
But I don’t really know how to implement it (am new to InnoSetupCompiler)? And I read this “…splash screen effect before the installer starts the setup procedure” on the page, is like I it is the opposite I wanted (A splash screen effect the shows when the app is launch from the desktop, or start menu).

Comment: @TLama, I text your “InnoImageAnimator”, which is ok. But how do I add such InnoImageAnimator to my app so that when it is launched from a user’s PC desktop, or start menu is shows the animation before launching the main app?
Thanks for your time all in advance.

Comment: @Umar, I've updated my answer above with link to instructions. If you want a splash-screen for when the user initiates your inno-installer application then I beleive this is the functionality you need. However, maybe I missunderstood your original question, do you mean a splash-screen for the application that inno installs on the host computer?

Comment: @Lars, thanks for your time. But you misunderstood my question, I mean a splash-screen for the application that inno installs on the host computer. The solution above isn't what am looking for.

The splash-screen should be after installation, anytime the user wants to start/launch the app he will see the slash-screen. Hope am clear enough now? Thanks in advance

Comment: @Umar, I'm sorry but I cannot see how Inno-setup could easily solve your request. Typically a splash-screen is implemented in the application that is being launched...

Comment: Huffffffff! OK, I used Python to developed the app, any idea how to implement that in python? Or can you suggest an installer that can do that?