# InnoSetup, silent install with "splash"

Tags: inno-setup

Is it possible to create an installer like Atom (the text editor) has, with Inno Setup?

Atom has an installer that automatically starts to install the application as soon as the user opens the .exe-file. And it simply displays an undecorated window with an animated gif during the installation.

I've googled something about silent installs, but is it possible to display an image, ideally an animated gif, during the installation, and finally launch the application without prompting the user?

Comment: For the splash screen, take a look at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23960516/inno-setup-compiler-how-to-set-launching-image-during-app-loading. I think you need to code the setup manually to do a silent installation, e.g. in `procedure InitializeWizard()`

Comment: I actually already found that post, but I got the impression from the ISSI docs that it displays the image only before the installation starts.

Comment: function InitializeSetup(): Boolean; is called as very first - use it to show splash (however form is not yet constructed).